# Is there a color / theme for Android Studio IDE that separates blocks of code into different colored blocks?

Tags: android-studio

When you have a lot of nested blocks it gets harder to see where the end of each block ends by just looking at the indentions. (I have a small screen) Are there color themes that can separate code blocks into different colors or shades so that it's easier to view?

Comment: Goto settings in android studio and then Editor and code style, customize whatever things you required

Comment: @Brendon it doesn't look like it has that. Thanks for the suggestion anyways

Comment: Are you really having that much nested blocks? It looks to me a bit like a code smell, did you consider refactoring the code? for example, using early returns (https://betterprogramming.pub/are-early-returns-any-good-eed4b4d03866)

Comment: @qki my personal process is that i build it that way, and when there's no more issues,  refactor and split them up. hate jumping to different areas, messes with my thought flow.  when you have the debugger open plus the emulator, so little of the code can be seen any more. also using flutter where the widget trees are expansive. Still a newbie.

Comment: its more about long lines nests, rather than deep nests-of-nests